# providing user to choose input field or combobox based

Tags: jsp, jquery, spring-mvc

I want to provide user both with selectbox or input so that he can enter either way

for exmaple http://www.redbus.in/ in this website they provided the user to select from either through input or combobox onkeyup()

Comment: have a google for jquery autocomplete

Comment: useful http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: Try this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: can't we implement on it on our own i mean with using auto complete.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to create your own autocomplete? The jquery autocomplete is very easy to use, used it many a times.